# Euler type problem, why roots are $m_- < 0 < m_+$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the following Euler problem:

$$\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 S^2 \frac{\mathrm{d}^2 V}{\mathrm{d}S^2} + rS \frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}S}-rV = 0$$

we have that $E,S^*,\sigma,r > 0$. I assume that the solutions are of the form $S^{m}$. We know that the roots are real and distinct because $b^2-4ac>0$. I find that $m_{\pm}$ are the following form: $m_+ = \frac{\sqrt{2r}\sigma S}{\sigma^2 S^2}$ and $m_- = \frac{-\sqrt{2r}\sigma S -2rS+\sigma^2 S^2}{\sigma^2 S^2}$. In my notes it says that $m_- < 0 < m_+$. I can easily see why $m_+ > 0$ and clearly $m_+ > m_-$, but how do we know that $m_- < 0$?

Comment: Maybe it is fine to solve your equation first?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The product of the roots is $-\dfrac{2\,r}{\sigma^2}<0$. They must have different sign.