# Initial condition of the euler DE implication

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This question links to the problem described here: [Euler type problem, why roots are $m_- < 0 < m_+$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1585409/euler-type-problem-why-roots-are-m-0-m). The general solution to that problem is $$V(S) = AS^{m^+}+BS^{m_-}$$ given the initial condition that $V(0)=0$, why does it imply that $B=0$ and thus that $V(S)=AS^{m^+}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $$V(S) = AS^{a}+BS^{-b}$$ is a solution to differential equation, it is assumed that $V(S)$ is defined and continuous at all points in the domain of the problem. However, $S^{-b}$ isn't defined at $S=0$ (note also it is not removable discontinuity), while $V(S)$ does, after all we have $V(0)=0$ , therefore to fulfill the the initial condition one have to assume that $B=0$.

Comment: Oh I see. Because we would be raising zero to a negative power which implies division be zero. Got it.  Still need to understand why $m_-$ is less than zero. But that is a different question.  Thanks